# When should I use a t-test versus an ANOVA?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, anova, t-test

I have data of bacterial abundances in different treatments (triplicates).  The treatments test 3 factors: Location (root/soil), Fungi (added/none), and Insect (added/none).

I would like to determine which bacterial abundances significantly change upon the addition of Fungi, irrespective of the presence of the insect.

I first performed ANOVA (for the root and soil subsets separately):

`aov(df[,i]~df$Fungi*df$Insect)` with i being the bacterial abundances

Then I performed t-tests:

`t.test(df_Fungi,df_noFungi)`

The results 'mostly' agree with each other, but  some bacterial changes are significant with the ANOVA and not the t-tests.

Is one of these approaches more 'correct' than the other?

Comment: Quick answer:  you will probably be better off constructing a single model that includes all the main factors and interactions of interest.  I could see how you may want to run Root and Soil separately, though it also may make sense to put them in the same model.

Answer (score 4):

The most significant (so to speak) difference between them is that the t-test is to test whether **two** groups of samples belongs to the same population (that is whether they might be identically distributed). It does this by checking the ratio between the differences in the means and standard deviations.

However, if you have *more* than two, ANOVA is (usually*) the way to go.  the The paired t-test is based on the fact that $t^2=f$, and ANOVA also uses the $f$isher distribution in a generalized way, such that it generalizes almost nicely$^!$. In other words when plain (one-way) ANOVA is used for only two populations, then they should be identical, since

Moreover, you can do a two-way ANOVA, and apply stuff like randomized block design and so fort.

However, here by doing the multiplication sign, you're doing interaction between the factors. That is actually a two-way ANOVA.

```
aov(df[,i]~df$Fungi*df$Insect)
```

is identical to

```
aov(df[,i]~df$Fungi+df$Insect+df$Fungi:df$Insect)
```

where `df$Fungi:df$Insect` denotes the interaction between those two variables. However, if you replace it with 
    aov(df[,i]~df$Fungi+df$Insect)
(note the `+` instead of `*`) I'm fairly certain you should get the same results as the `t.test`.

*: There are of course other tests, like a multiple t$^2$-test.

Comment: By "population" do you mean group? A sample is drawn from a population in which a proportion of either belongs to one of two or more groups.

Comment: "Interaction" is the correct word.  "Interaction between the factors" I think makes sense in English and is also typical.

Comment: @AdamO I guess I could clean up the terminology a bit. With the $t^2$ test, we’re testing whether the sample means and variances are equal in both sample “groups”. Which is, in effect, testing whether they are from the same distribution. In addition we assume that the dependent variables are (approximately) normal iid. I’ll update answer with these tomorrow :)

Comment: @SalMangiafico in Norwegian we use a word that directly translates to “co-play variables”. I felt that interaction variables was the best I could come up with.

Answer (score 3):

A t-test is just a special case of the ANOVA when you have only a single independent variable that has only two groups (e.g., you are simply comparing two means). In this case $t^2 = F$. You have run to different models. You ANOVA is a two-way ANOVA (2 by 2), testing both the main effects of Fungi and Insect and the interaction of the two. What happened to Location? Shouldn't it be in the model as well? The t-test test the mean difference for Fungi but if insect or location are unbalanced between the two groups, then this could be biased. Your question implies that you want to test Fungi, holding insect constant. Thus, an ANOVA without interaction with all three factors (Fungi, Insect, and Location) would be most appropriate. The effect you are interested in is the main effect for Fungi. Assuming Insect and Location have an effect on the DV, this test will also have more power (well, assuming the effect is large enough to offset the cost in dfs).